# Why can I see my own deleted answers but not questions?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions

When deleting an answer, even after refreshing the page I still see it (but with red background and such). But with questions, the behavior is different, yielding a 404 error and such.

For instance, one of my deleted questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347223/simplest-way-to-parse-out-spurious-whitespace

I can't see it at all. I get "page not found".

Why is this behavior inconsistent? What harm is there in me being able to see my own deleted questions? It'd be nice to be able to bookmark a deleted question and come back to it, seeing what you wrote and deciding if you want it undeleted. With answers you can do that, but not questions.